# ASP.NET Core MVC ActionFilter executing after Authorization fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC Core application that has two filters. One is an `AuthorizeFilter` to check Role membership, and the other is an `ActionFilter` that verifies that the application and database are in sync.

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new RoleRequirement()).Build()));
            options.Filters.Add(new DatabaseFilter());
        })
```

If there is a mismatch the `ActionFilter` returns a view displaying the error message.

DatabaseFilter.cs:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        context.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "DbError"
        };
    }
}
```

RoleRequirement.cs:

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Fail();
    }

    return;
}
```

What is happening is that **if an unauthorized user uses the application when there is a database mismatch, they are shown the database error view instead of getting a 403 Forbidden response** like they would if there was no database mismatch. I would prefer that they receive the forbidden message instead.

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters), the `AuthorizationFilter` runs before the `ActionFilter`, but it must not be short-circuiting the request even after setting `context.Fail()`.

Comment: Can you source "According to the documentation"?

Comment: Added reference to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

After going back to this it became obvious. The Authorization Filter *is* short-circuiting the request... which then directs to an Error controller action to return a custom 403 page. The error controller has no authorization, so it then falls down to the DatabaseFilter, which returns the mismatch error as it should.